# Difference between Layout(Linear,Relative, etc) & Container Views(ListView,GridView etc)?

Tags: android, android-layout

Difference between Layout & Container Views? 
First of all It is not meant if duplicate answers are their it must be correct. They answers the question according to definition but According to Visualization & According to Android Studio they are different & yet not explained in details.

[image]

Comment: already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677654/what-is-the-difference-between-a-layout-and-a-container-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a Layout and a Container in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677654/what-is-the-difference-between-a-layout-and-a-container-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Layout :** define the arrangement of Views inside a root Container View

**View :** the child Views inside a Container View.

**Container View :** A View that can contain child Views and nested Container Views, they are classes extended from Android ViewGroup class. Some Container View classes are RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout, RecyclerView etcetera